# Como imprimir o conteúdo de um Objeto em uma Lista<>

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, jee

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em JAVA na qual irá exibir o conteúdo de um objeto de uma lista. Meu objetivo é imprimir o conteúdo de objeto de uma lista.

```
package teste1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import teste1.ProductMovement;



public class Teste {

    private List<ProductMovement> filterFractionedMovements(List<ProductMovement> reservMovements) {

        return reservMovements;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Creating a list 


        List<ProductMovement> pro = new ArrayList<ProductMovement>();
        ProductMovement p = new ProductMovement();

        p.setId(1);
        p.setNome("Teste1");
        pro.add(0,p);

      System.out.println( ??????);

    }
}
```

Tenho exibir o conteudo aqui nesse trecho:

> System.out.println( ??????);

Código ProductMovement:

```
package teste1;

public class ProductMovement {
    private int id;
    private String nome;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

}
```

Comment: Nós também não sabemos o que quer imprimir, o problema é pegar o elemento da lista ou imprimir o objeto? São duas coisas distintas.

Comment: imprimir o objeto

Comment: System.out.println(pro.get(0).getNome());

Comment: consegui era apenas adicionar isso